# How to write IEqualityComparer for anonymous variables in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to know there is a way to implement IEqualityComparer for anonymous variables in a lambda expression or, in any case, I need to write class to transform anonymous variables to the sprecific class and create a class where I need to implement IEqualtyComparer ?

I write code which create Cartesian(Decart's) production:
I defined class Decart.

```
public class Decart
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

I defined IEqualtityComparer for Decart class

```
public class Ext : IEqualityComparer<Decart>
{

    public bool Equals(Decart x, Decart y)
    {
        if ((x.X == y.X && x.Y == y.Y) ||
            x.X == y.Y && x.Y == y.X)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Decart obj)
    {
        return obj.X + obj.Y;
    }
}
```

I run this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Ext ext = new Ext();
    IEnumerable<int> input = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);
        var secondResult = input
        .SelectMany(x => input.Select(y => new Decart{ X = x, Y = y }))
        .Distinct(new Ext());
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));

    foreach (var x in secondResult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", x.X, x.Y));
    }
    //output:
    //1 1
    //1 2
    //1 3
    //2 2
    //2 3
    //3 3
}
```

I want to run next code without defining a class for anonymous variables, a class for implementing IEqualityComparer.

```
    var thirdResult = input
        .SelectMany(x => input
            .SelectMany(y => input
                .Select(z => new { x, y, z })))
                    .Distinct( ???? );

//in this case output need to be like this:
//1 1 1
//1 2 1
//1 3 1
//2 1 2
//2 2 2
//2 3 2
//3 1 3
//3 2 3
//3 3 3
```

How to do it ?

Comment: It looks like you are defining equality with the same per-property equality that anonymous objects get by default, so why not just use `Distinct()` with no comparer passed so that the default is used?

Comment: @JonHanna  with Distinct() I get this result:
    //1 1
    //1 2
    //1 3
    //2 1
    //2 2
    //2 3
    //3 1
    //3 2
    //3 3
 
 with Distinct(new Ext()) I get this result:
    //1 1
    //1 2
    //1 3
    //2 2
    //2 3
    //3 3

Comment: Ah, it's not caring about order. Sorry, I read too quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation which would take delegates as implementation for `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods of interface. Then you can pass-in anonymous methods as implementation.

```
public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateEqualityComparer<T>(T ignore, Func<T, int> getHashCode, Func<T, T, bool> equals) => new DelegatedEqualityComparer<T>(getHashCode, equals);

public class DelegatedEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T> {
    private Func<T, int> getHashCode;
    private Func<T, T, bool> equals;
    public DelegatedEqualityComparer(Func<T, int> getHashCode, Func<T, T, bool> equals) {
        if(getHashCode==null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getHashCode));
        if(equals==null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equals));
        this.getHashCode=getHashCode;
        this.equals=equals;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(T x) => getHashCode(x);
    public override bool Equals(T x, T y) => equals(x, y);
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
var equalityComparer = CreateEqualityComparer(true ? null : new { x = 0, y = 0 }, a => a.x+a.y, (a, b) => (a.x==b.x&&a.y==b.y)||(a.x==b.y&&a.y==b.x));
var result = input
    .SelectMany(x => input
        .Select(y => new { x, y }))
    .Distinct(equalityComparer);
```

### Meaning of `true ? null : new { x = 0, y = 0 }`:

First argument to CreateEqualityComparer (`T ignore`) is needed to allow compiler to infer type `T`, as you can not spell name of anonymous type. `true` condition of ternary operator make compiler to always select left branch `null`, but as both branches of ternary operator must return the same type, then `new { x = 0, y = 0 }` make compiler to implicitly cast `null` to given anonymous type.

Also, relevant note from specification:

> 7.6.10.6 Anonymous object creation expressions
>   Within the same program, two anonymous object initializers that specify a sequence of properties of the same names and compile-time types in the same order will produce instances of the same anonymous type.

Comment: Perhaps explain the purpose of the ternary and the significance of the dummy parameter?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 The C# compiler can't discern the type T (used by the static method `CreateEqualityComparer`) from the delegates, so you pass him an object of type T (`new { x = 0, y = 0 }`), but PetSer is someone that loves to optimize code, and he thought that creating an useless object was bad, so the ternary operator `true ? null : new ` that won't create the object, but still the compiler can discern the type of the not-created object :-) (I think that the ternary "thing" was wonderful :-) )

Comment: @xantos I know the answer. I'm suggesting it might help someone else, particularly the OP or anyone who wants to do something similar with anonymous types. If they knew the significance / the why of it they wouldn't necessarily need to have asked the question in the first place

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 In the v1 of your comment you wrote that you know, still my comment is "correct" :-) Simply it isn't for "you" it is for "them" :-)

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, the perils of writing comments on your phone :-). I wasn't suggesting your comment was incorrect at all. I'm just suggesting that the answer could be improved by elaborating on what that does. If I was a beginner I wouldn't understand the purpose of it. Answers that work are great for copy/paste, but an explanation would be even better. There are several topics in this post: type inference, generics and anonymous types (and how the compiler generates the same type). I'd write my own answer but it'd be pretty much identical, hence the comments

Comment: Shouldn't you implement `IEqualityComparer<>` instead of inherit from `EqualityComparer`?

Comment: @NetMage It is one of possible options too.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're asking.

I assume you want to generilize the dimensions of this class like

```
public class Decart
{
    public int[] dim;
}
```

then you can extend the comparer

```
public class Ext : IEqualityComparer<Decart>
{

    public bool Equals(Decart x, Decart y)
    {
        for(int i=0; i< x.dim.Length;i++) 
        if (x.dim[i] != y.dim[i] ) 
            return false; 
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Decart obj)
    {
        return obj.dim.Sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know, if any way to write IEqualityComparer in Distinct method for anonymous variables (class). How I understand, unfortunately, there is no way to do it.